# GameObject.Find() works in editor, but returns null in build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mapbox, unity-webgl

I'm currently using `GameObject.Find()` to retrieve an object generated by the Mapbox Unity SDK. The code works fine in the editor, but when I build the project it returns null. The offending code is the following:

```
GameObject go = GameObject.Find ("16/32699/21126");
if(go != null) {
    //do the thing
} else {
    Debug.Log("the tile doesn't exist");
}
```

I've tried building in both WebGL and Native OSX, both with the same result.

in the editor, the exact name of the object I'm looking for in the scene hierarchy is `16/32699/21126`. I appreciate that using the forward slash is how you search for sub-children in unity, but it seemed to work fine in the editor.

below is a screenshot of the scene hierarchy.

[image: scene hierarchy]

The behaviour script is attached to the `Map` object.

Do you know what could be causing this, or if there is another way of searching for the object I'm after?

Comment: Are you deactivating the "16/32699/21126" object with the `SetActive(false)` function or destroying it with the `Destroy` function anywhere in the scene?

Comment: @Programmer I'm not personally, but I can't say for sure what the Mapbox SDK is doing. I can see the object in the game though, so I'm pretty sure it's  still active.

Comment: Mapbox SDK is either changing the name of that object, destroying it or you are searching for that object even before Mapbox SDK creates it. You can make sure the problem is not `GameObject.Find ("16/32699/21126");` by creating a new scene with just an Object called "16/32699/21126" then search for it with `GameObject.Find ("16/32699/21126");`. You should find it.

Comment: Try also getting the transform of the map and then using `FindChild()`, if that doesn't work, iterate over the map's children and try and find it yourself that way (debug.log the names of the children found that *aren't* the one you're looking for, too!)

Comment: I suggest getting rid of `.Find()` calls entirely. Even if you fix it following @Programmer 's recommendations, all it takes for the error to come back, without any compiler warning, is for names to change, which can happen in any future refactoring or by another plugin. --- A singleton or a different approach for dependency-injection tying the *reference* to the object itself, rather than it's *name*, would be far better.

Comment: don't use slashes in names, slashes are for paths. Read documentation https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html

"If name contains a '/' character, it traverses the hierarchy like a path name."

Comment: @Michel-F.Portzert If it that's true, it doesn't really matter. That should work and works on my side in any build. The issue has nothing to do with slash.

Comment: so I've (sort of) found a solution. I've stopped using `Find()` and instead now use `transform.GetChild()` to get the elements I'm after. Doing this works fine in the final build, so there was an issue with `Find()` after all. 
Now I appreciate that this isn't an ideal solution, and is very much a quick fix for a PoC I'm demoing in a few days. To do it properly, You should be able to use the Mapbox SDK Stack pipeline to target the element with a bit more certainty

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access the tile through the map visualises..
example code.

```
UnwrappedTileId unwrappedTileId = Conversions.LatitudeLongitudeToTileId(latLon.x, latLon.y, (int)_mapManager.Zoom); //either use lat,lon or other way to get unwraptileid

    var tile = _mapManager.MapVisualizer.ActiveTiles[unwrappedTileId];//_mapManager is your abstract map
//active tiles is the dictionary created by mapbox sdk to track which tiles are active
    if(null!= tile)
    {
        myModel.transform.SetParent(tile.transform, true);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Map tile is null");
    }
```